# UPDATE row with ID in Azure SQL table with pyodbc (passing variables)

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am attempting to update an entire row with a specific ID in my azure SQL database **using pyodbc**. I currently have the below query but know that the syntax is not correct.

```
 def update_invoice(fullName, invoiceNo, date, address, description, total, invoiceID):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE dbo.customerInvoices (customerName, invoiceNo, invoiceDate, customerAddress, invoiceDescription, invoiceTotal) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (fullName, invoiceNo, date, address, description, total), "WHERE id=?", (invoiceID))
    cnxn.commit()
```

As you can see I am passing multiple variables to the query. The query is in 2 parts:

1. Specifying the columns and what data to enter
2. Specifying the row to enter the data into

I have used `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)` and `WHERE id=?` in other queries and it works perfectly well. I am just struggling to combine them in 1 query.

Incase this is useful, here is what my table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look like an [`UPDATE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)... not sure where you got it from, anyway, here is one that does what you asked.

```py
def update_invoice(fullName, invoiceNo, date, address, description, total, invoiceID):
    cursor.execute(
        """\
            UPDATE dbo.customerInvoices 
            SET customerName = ?
                , invoiceNo = ?
                , invoiceDate = ?
                , customerAddress = ?
                , invoiceDescription = ?
                , invoiceTotal = ?
            WHERE id = ?;
        """,
        (fullName, invoiceNo, date, address, description, total, invoiceID)
    )
    cnxn.commit()
```